# Qual è il significato di "far capo" in questo brano?

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *Il barone rampante*, di Italo Calvino, ho letto:

> Cosimo lo mise sotto a far calcoli e disegni, e in tanto interessò i proprietari dei boschi privati, gli appaltatori dei boschi demaniali, i taglialegna, i carbonai. Tutti insieme, sotto la direzione del Cavalier Avvocato (ossia, il Cavalier Avvocato sotto tutti loro, forzato a dirigerli e a non distrarsi) e con Cosimo che sovrintendeva ai lavori dall'alto, costruirono delle riserve d'acqua in modo che in ogni punto in cui fosse scoppiato un incendio si sapesse dove **far capo** con le pompe.

Potreste spiegarmi il significato dell'espressione "far capo" in questo passaggio?

Nel [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/capo/) ho trovato

> *fare capo*, andare a finire, sboccare: *è una strada che fa c. alla piazza del Municipio; non capivo dove andasse a far c. il suo discorso*; *far c. a qualcuno*, rivolgersi o ricorrere a lui, spec. per aiuto o consiglio

Tuttavia, non mi sembra che queste definizioni abbiano senso nel contesto del brano sopra citato.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Credo che in questo caso sia utile il significato di *fare capo* come "affidarsi, appoggiarsi, ricorrere, riferirsi, rivolgersi" (http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/capo_%28Sinonimi-e-Contrari%29/).

Calvino intende che in previsione di un incendio erano state predisposte delle riserve d'acqua in modo che chi fosse accorso per spegnere le fiamme avrebbe saputo dove andare per attingere l'acqua con le pompe. Progettare un efficace sistema antincendio (il romanzo si svolge nel Settecento) significava dunque evitare che i boschi (e quindi le riserve di legname per costruire, scaldare, cucinare) andassero distrutti rapidamente.